# jQuery looping .each() Using JSON Stream Object

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

***JS FILE***

```
var IMController = {
    listIM: function () {
        var params = getUrlVars($("#getIM").attr("href"));
        $.ajax({
            url: "listIM",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $.extend(params, {
                _tzcm: new Date().getTime()
            }),
            success: function (data) {



            } // success
        });
        return false;
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getIM").click(function () {

        IMController.listIM();

        return false;
    });
});
```

***This code is from my JAVA CLASS***

```
for (int i = 0; i < ims.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject imJsonObject = new JSONObject();
    imJsonObject.put("imID", ims.get(i).getImID());
    imJsonObject.put("text", ims.get(i).getText());
    imJsonObject.put("dateTime", ims.get(i).getDateTime());
    imJsonObject.put("toAccountID", ims.get(i).getToAccountID());
    imJsonObject.put("toUserFullName", (ims.get(0).getToUser().getFirstName() != null ? ims.get(0).getToUser().getFirstName() : "") + " " + (ims.get(0).getToUser().getLastName() != null ? ims.get(0).getToUser().getLastName() : ""));
    imJsonObject.put("fromUserFullName", (user.getFirstName() != null ? user.getFirstName() : "") + " " + (user.getLastName() != null ? user.getLastName() : ""));
    imJsonObject.put("fromAccountID", ims.get(i).getFromAccountID());
    jsonArray.put(imJsonObject);
}
```

I have succeeded in getting my JSON object from my Action. I have tried many times to print the returned data using "each" function, but I couldn't. I don't know why.

---

***well finally  i figured out where the error is  .  it s in my getUrlVars function .  I m using this function to get attributes from the href link and use it in "data : attribute"    . here s the code of this function***

```
function getUrlVars(url)
{
    var vars = {};
    var hash;
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];

    }
    return vars;
}
```

**TypeError: vars.push is not a function vars.push(hash[0]);**

Comment: where is the fiddle? or give the JSON output that you got

Comment: @AbdullaChozhimadathil - there's no rule that says everything has to be posted to jsFiddle. OP provided their code, as they're supposed to.

Comment: @sphanley There doesn't have to be a jsFiddle, but there needs to be more information than this. @OP Where is your attempt to use the `each()` function? I don't see `each` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @JLRishe I don't disagree, but there's no need for someone to come in here and have a flippant attitude with a new member as though a jsFiddle is specifically required.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem when you use $.each() ?

```
var IMController = {
    listIM: function () {
        var params = getUrlVars($("#getIM").attr("href"));
        $.ajax({
            url: "listIM",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $.extend(params, {
                _tzcm: new Date().getTime()
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
                   doWhateverWithObject(obj);
                })


            } // success
        });
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: well i don't know how to use my each function in the right way .  every time i try it this is what i get [{"text":"test im","fromAccountID":1,"dateTime":2014-09-25 17:14:06.0,"toAccountID":2,"imID":1,"fromUserFullName":"admin admin","toUserFullName":"fname lname"},{"text":"test test","fromAccountID":2,"dateTime":2014-09-25 17:14:06.0,"toAccountID":1,"imID":2,"fromUserFullName":"admin admin","toUserFullName":"fname lname"}]

Answer (score 0):

Data seems to be jsonArray of jsonObjects. Try it, you can get object properties like "text" inside a loop each.

```
$.each(data, function(index, jsonObject){
   console.log(jsonObject.text);
});
```